# php Encode and decode html tags

Tags: php

i am using html_entity_decode($str) for decode html tags, but it cannot be able to decode the text. it show ? for " " in output... i have used htmlentities also to encode it and at display time i decode it also. but the problem is not solve.you can watch the output at 'http://www.aspits.com/aspits/testimonials.php'. i am suffering from this please help me. i have tried so much things for it but i am not be able to get the solution for this. in database it appear correct means in database the entry is "test" but when i show it on front end then it display ?test?  like this as output...

Answer (score 1):

Do your character sets in database and HTML match?

If not, make them.
Assuming you are using UTF-8.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content=text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I'll also assume MySQL (please tag what database you are using).

```
SET NAMES 'utf-8'
```

#### Update

Just looked at [your site](http://www.aspits.com/aspits/testimonials.php). You are informing the browser you are using UTF-8.

Please check your database.

Comment: thanks for your response...  i am using mysql as database and i use the meta tag as you show me but what you want to tell me i can't able to understand what you want to say . what is means of SET NAMES 'utf-8'
where should i use this and why...  please tell me

Comment: @Abhishek You should run that query. e.g. `mysql_query('SET NAMES \'utf-8\'')`.